# Install Google Cloud Storage Client Library with pip -- Python GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pip, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

I am trying to use pip to install the Google Cloud Storage Client Library for Google App Engine.  I appreciate any hints you may have. My documentation says to enter this in the command prompt:

```
pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient -t <app_root>
```

so I am literally entering:

```
pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient -t C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine
```

but i keep getting an error regarding a "Missing distribution spec":

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 232, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 305, in run

    name, None, isolated=options.isolated_mode,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 181, in from
_line
    isolated=isolated)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 54, in __ini
t__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", li
ne 2873, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", li
ne 2807, in parse_requirements
    raise ValueError("Missing distribution spec", line)
ValueError: ('Missing distribution spec', '(x86)\\Google\\google_appengine')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your current error, since there are spaces in your path you should quote it:

```
pip install GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient -t "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine"
```

However, the directory you should install to is your actual project directory, as in the one that contains your `app.yaml`.

Comment: Jaime - that worked, thanks for that clarification.  The app is now finding the cloudstorage module, but I am getting a new error.  Not sure if it is related to the location of of the GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient or just some other issue with the code I am testing.  Here is the error:    File "C:\Users\mellis\Desktop\international\Python for App Engine Examples\Chapter03 - Copy\cloudstorage\common.py", line 243, in validate_file_path

    'but got %s' % path)

Comment: Looks to me it's related to the actual app code, if you keep having problems after debugging you could craft a new question :)